# Wrong results from matrix inversion

Tags: fortran, matrix-inverse

I'd like to make a function which makes inversion of matrix.

I use the algorithm

```
Ax(j) = I(j)
```

where `x` is inversion of `A`, `x(j)` is `j`-th column of `x`, `I(j)` is `j`-th column of the identity matrix. Then I merge the column vectors and make the inversion of the matrix. So I made implemented the algorithm for Gaussian elimination and inversion of the matrix.

```
program inversion
    implicit none
    real(4), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A,B
    real(4), dimension(4,1) :: c

    A = reshape((/2,-1,0,0,-1,2,-1,0,0,-1,2,-1,0,0,-1,2/),(/4,4/))
    c = reshape((/1,2,3,4/),(/4,1/))

    write(*,*), inverse(A)

    contains
    function gauss_eli(A,b) result(z)
        implicit none
        integer :: n, i, j, k
        real(4) :: factor, s
        real(4), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A
        integer, dimension(2) :: m
        real(4), dimension(int(sum(shape(A))/2),1) :: b
        real(4), dimension(int(sum(shape(b)))) :: z
        m = shape(A)
        n = m(1)
        do k=1,n-1
            do i=k+1,n
                factor = A(i,k)/A(k,k)
                do j=k+1,n
                    A(i,j)=A(i,j)-factor*A(k,j)
                enddo
                b(i,1) = b(i,1)-factor*b(k,1)
            enddo
        enddo
        z(n) = b(n,1)/A(n,n)
        do i=n-1,1,-1
            s = b(i,1)
            do j=i+1,n
                s = s-A(i,j)*z(j)
            enddo
            z(i) = s/A(i,i)
        enddo
    end function

    function upper(A) result(x)
        implicit none
        integer :: i,k,n,j
        real(4) :: factor
        real(4), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A
        integer, dimension(2) :: m
        real(4), dimension(int(sum(shape(A))/2),int(sum(shape(A)))/2) :: x
        m = shape(A)
        n = m(1)
        x = A
        do k=1,n-1
            do i=k+1,n
                factor = x(i,k)/x(k,k)
                do j=k,n
                    x(i,j)=x(i,j)-factor*x(k,j)
                enddo
            enddo
        enddo
    end function

    function lower(A) result(y)
        implicit none
        integer :: i,j,k,n
        integer, dimension(2) :: m
        real(4) :: c
        real(4), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A, B
        real(4), dimension(int(sum(shape(A))/2),int(sum(shape(A)))/2) :: y
        B = upper(A)
        m = shape(A)
        n = m(1)
        !L(i,j) = 1/U(i,j)*(A(i,j)-sig(1 to j-1){L(i,k)U(k,j)})        
        do j=1,n
            do i=j,n
                if (j==1) then
                    y(i,j) = A(i,j)/B(j,j)
                else
                    c = 0
                    do k=1,j-1
                        c = c + y(i,k)*B(k,j)
                    enddo
                    y(i,j) = (A(i,j)-c)/B(j,j)
                endif
            enddo
        enddo

        do i=1,n
            do j=1,n
                if (i<j) then
                    y(i,j) = 0
                endif
            enddo
        enddo
    end function

    function iden(A) result(g)
        implicit none
        real(4), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A
        real(4), dimension(int(sum(shape(A))/2),int(sum(shape(A)))/2) :: g
        integer :: i,j,n
        integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: m
        m = shape(A)
        n = m(1)
        do i=1,n
            do j=1,n
                if (i==j) then
                    g(i,j) = 1.0
                else
                    g(i,j) = 0.0
                endif
            enddo
        enddo
    end function

    function inverse(A) result(z)
        implicit none
        integer :: c,n,i
        real(4), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A
        real(4), dimension(int(sum(shape(A))/2),int(sum(shape(A))/2)) :: h,z,d
        integer, dimension(2) :: m
        real(4), allocatable, dimension(:) :: B
        m = shape(A)
        n = m(1)
        d = iden(A)
        do c=1,n
            B = gauss_eli(A,d(:,c))
            do i=1,n
                z(i,c) = B(i)
            enddo
        enddo

        !write(*,*), u
    end function


end program
```

But I can't get the right inversion of A: [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWYVS.png)

Is the code wrong?

Comment: Do you use any modules or interface blocks? Please supply a full code we can test. And describe what happens wrong with your code. Any error messages? How do they look like? Wrong results? Why are they wrong and how should the correct result look like?

Comment: i put the matrix  A = reshape((/2,-1,0,0,-1,2,-1,0,0,-1,2,-1,0,0,-1,2/),(/4,4/)) and then write(*,*) inverse(A) the result is 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, -0.5714283, -1,142857, -2,142857, -1,714285, -0.9130432, -1.826086, -0.9130432, 0.5217387 NaN NaN NaN NaN

Comment: And what happens? Please show the **full code** and the **full output**. And [edit] the question with the new information, do not use comments.

Comment: you function `gauss_eli` modifies the matrix `A`, so as you call it repeatedly you are inverting a dlfferent matrix each time  (why do the gauss elimination one colunm at a time anyway?)

Comment: thanks agentp, i try to edit the code. Very Very thanks :)

Comment: Please show the results as text, not as a picture. There is a good reason why the system does not allow you to show the picture directly. Explain what the result means.

Comment: Well at the very least you are using z(i) before you have defined z for the given value of i in gauss_eli. And I'll also mention Write( *, * ) with a trailing comma is not standard, that use of explicit constants for kinds, e.g. real(4), makes the baby jesus cry, that you really should learn about the Size intrinsic (dimension(int(sum(shape(A))/2),1) is utterly bizarre and I haven't bothered to check if it is right), please use Intents, and possibly most importantly learn about Subroutines! Really, the way you have coded it shows that in fact one can't right Fortran in any language.